# Communication from DMZ to LAN

Tags: .net, rest, websocket, communication, long-polling

I have a system with two .net core WEB.API services, one on a company internal network (LAN) and one on an external server (DMZ). The DMZ service need to receive information from the service on the LAN. The problem is that there is a complete block of communication into the internal network (LAN), due to information security.

I know solutions like IBM DataPower proxy to override this issue but in my case I like to avoid this solution and fix it on the software level (No IT department, Integrations and so on...)

I thought about solving this problem in several ways:

**One way**: by long polling from the LAN service to the DMZ service.

**Second way**: Use WebSockets to make the connection and bypass the firewall.
         the DMZ will hold the WebSockets service and the LAN will be a WebSockets 
         client.

These two ways seems a kind of bypass. I'm looking for something that is more intuitive in terms of syntax, which is actually behave like a client-server mechanism from the DMZ to LAN service.

The syntax that I like to achieve is something like:
Server - LAN:

```
string GetCustomerId(string name){
   ....
}
```

Client - DMZ:

```
var id = client.GetCustomerId("abc");
```

Of course the solution must be with only one way communication from the LAN to the DMZ.
I appreciate any help, how to do this right?

Answer (score 4):

The solution I found is to use [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with two queues (Requests, Responses), one for each direction.
In the LAN you need to run a service that listen to Requests queue, handle with requests, and return a responses by the Responses queue.

On the DMZ you can run an API that foreword the request to the LAN by Requests queue, each request must contain a unique identifier. after inserting the request to the Requests queue, you will need to listen to Responses queue until you receive message with the same unique identifier.

You can add some extra security like encrypt messages before insert to queue, etc.